# How to insert a zero instead of a NULL in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to insert 0 in place of null?

Is this correct

```
INSERT INTO TEMP(ID,NAME) SELECT ID,NVL(NAME,0) FROM TEST;
```

Comment: Stackoverflow should not be used to resolve your home statements!

Comment: This is the sort of question you could easily answer for yourself by running your SQL in a database. If you don't have a local installation to use you should sign up for Oracle's LiveSQL cloud environment. [Find it here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/index.html)

Answer (score 7):

You can use any of the option below.

**Using `NVL()`**

```
SELECT ID
    ,NVL(NAME, 0)
FROM TEST;
```

**Using `ANSI` standard `coalesce()`**

```
SELECT ID
    ,coalesce(NAME, '0')
FROM TEST;
```

**Using `CASE`**

```
SELECT ID
    ,CASE 
        WHEN NAME IS NOT NULL
            THEN NAME
        ELSE '0'
        END
FROM TEST;
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/QPK51783)**